# DB conn method + First character of a variable name in PHP

Tags: php, database, string

For my connectDB function I need to trim all parameters and I don't want to do it separately for each one.

```
$g_app = 'we bsite';

$g_dbc_type = '';
$g_dbc_host = '';
$g_dbc_user = '';
$g_dbc_pass = '';
$g_dbc_db = '';

function connectDB ( $app, $type, $host, $user, $pass, $db ) {
    if ( $app !== '' ) {
        $params_vals = array ( $app, $type, $host, $user, $pass, $db );

        // I WANT TO DO THIS... ----------------------------------------
        foreach ( $params_vals as $val ) {
            if ( $val !== '' ) {
                $trimmed_val = str_replace ( ' ', '', $val );
```

Get first char of a variable name? Because it's in foreach loop, I'm not sure if I am able to reach my target this way and if not, is there any other way?

```
                $first_char = '';

                if ( !isset ( ${ $first_char } ) ) {
                    $ { $first_char } = $trimmed_val;
                }
                else {
                    die (); // Variable should not been already set, but it is.
                }
                echo ${ $first_char } . ':<br />' . $trimmed_val;
            }
        }

        // ...INSTEAD OF THIS... -------------------------------------
        $a = str_replace ( ' ', '', $app );
        $t = str_replace ( ' ', '', $type );
        $h = str_replace ( ' ', '', $host );
        $u = str_replace ( ' ', '', $user );
        $p = str_replace ( ' ', '', $pass );
        $d = str_replace ( ' ', '', $db );

        // ...
        if ( $a === 'website' ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    else {
        die (); // App has not been chosen.
    }
}

connectDb ( $g_app, $g_dbc_type, $g_dbc_host, $g_dbc_user, $g_dbc_pass, $g_dbc_db );
```

Also, is this method of connection inconsistent with safety?

Thank you for your suggestions and feedbacks.

Comment: Usually the data used to connect to the database is hardcoded or retrieved from a trusted and secured config file.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because the firm IT infrastructure applications should be based on the same index I would like to connect to the database with only one function and this is the easiest way I could think of.

Comment: @ForguesR Everything about programming I learned at home so I do not know common methods. Could you suggest me other way with a few words? Also I am sorry for some typo, my English is not very good.

Comment: @ForguesR I must say that it is for fictional firm, it is only a summary test of my skills.

Comment: You mean you are going to connect to multiple databases at the same time?

Comment: @ForguesR For one app which will be only for localhost I want to use remote server database and local database, so yeah. But it would be written in some condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here, go crazy.

```
$params = array('test' => 'some things that are meant to be trimmed ');

function trimParams($params = NULL){
    if($params == NULL){
        return false;
    }

    foreach($params as $param => $value){
        $return[$param] = str_replace( ' ', '', $value);
    }   
    return $return;
}

print_r(trimParams($params));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current function arguments with [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.func-get-args.php) as an array.

Example from php.net

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arg_list); $i++) {
        echo "L'argument $i est : " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```